# Matlab Image thresholding

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

The following code shows an image that is combination of blue and red colors. But if I remove the `close` statement it yields a grayscale image (which is what I want).

Why  does it happen, so that I can avoid it in the future?

I am following [this tutorial on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FkUIwWQvJjU).

```
    clear;
    animal1=imread('animal1.jpg');

    %% GrayScale
    animal2=rgb2gray(animal1);

    %% scale
    bright=animal2*1.5;
    imshow(bright);
    close;

    %% threshold
    binary= bright>220;
    imagesc(binary);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call the `imshow` function, a new figure is created, and default `colormap` is set to `grayscale`. If you do not call close, the `imagesc` uses the same `colormap`, and uses gray levels to show the binary image.

Otherwise, the current figure is destroyed, a new one is created, and the `imagesc` function defines a new `colormap`. The default `colormap` in this case is `parula`, which shades from blue to yellow.

Note that you can display the binary image by using the `imshow` function directly.

Answer (score 1):

As [@dlegland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5998315/dlegland) has pointed out, it's an issue with colormaps.

In MATLAB a [colormap](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) defines the way that data (in your image, plot, whatever) is mapped to a color on the screen. This is done via a linear mapping which can be [different for each axes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/caxis.html).

When you call [`imshow`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html), it is a relatively high-level function which alters a number of properties of the axes on which is it displayed. This includes the colormap, color limits, and other things like the tick marks. In your case, since you fed it a grayscale image (you created using `rgb2gray`), it set the figure/axes to use the `gray` colormap.

[`imagesc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html), however, is a lower-level function that *doesn't* make any changes to the current axes with the exception that it alters the color limits to span the entire dynamic range of the image. Because of this, when you use `imagesc` to plot an image on an axes that was previously used by `imshow`. It simply uses the colormap that `imshow` was using (`gray`).

If `imshow` hadn't been called, then the figure would be using the default colormap (typically `parula`) and your image would be displayed using this colormap.

Now the nice thing is that you can change the colormap that is being used with the [`colormap`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) command. For example to use grayscale, you would do

```
colormap gray
```

Or if you wanted to specify that colormap for only a specific axes you could do the following

```
ax = axes();
colormap(ax, gray)
```

Your only options *aren't* `gray` or `parula`. MATLAB has a number of built-in [colormaps](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html#inputarg_name) or you can even specify your own custom colormap.